# Solving $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-1=0$ for $x\in[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

Which of these is a possible solution for
$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-1=0$$
in the interval $x\in[0,2\pi]$

a. $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$
b. $x=\pi$
c. $x=\frac{5\pi}{3}$
d. all of the above

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above.
The equation you wrote is basically a n identity and is true for all $x\in[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Even for all $x\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Bro the problem is on the $sin^2+cos^2=1$ don't even think drawing in the complex field is a good idea for the one who posted this XD

Comment: Quite true. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

like aryan said it is an identity.
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ for all $x$ therefore with a simple substitution you have $1-1=0$
so it is true for all $x$